# Android - align images in table Layout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to create a table row, which on the left are 3 images, and on the right a textview.
Something You can usually see in a game (on the right the level number, and on the left the number of lives left.)

I have tried this layout, but one of the images isnt aligns to the right: (The table layout is nested within linear layout)

```
 <TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:shrinkColumns="0"  
  android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow        
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
  <ImageView  
     android:id="@+id/wa1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:paddingRight="5px"
     android:paddingTop="6px"
     android:src="@drawable/v"/>
  <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/v" 
      android:paddingTop="6px" 
      android:layout_gravity="left" 
      android:id="@+id/wa2" 
      android:paddingRight="5px">
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/v" 
      android:paddingTop="6px" 
      android:layout_gravity="left" 
      android:id="@+id/wa3" 
      android:paddingRight="5px">
  </ImageView>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/question_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="26px"
    android:paddingLeft="125px"
    android:paddingRight="15px"
/>
</TableRow>
```

this is the relevant part of the result:
[image]

10X alot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `</TableRow>` is supposed to be followed by a `</TableLayout>`, try removing

```
android:shrinkColumns="0"  
android:stretchColumns="1"
```

from the TableLayout and

```
android:paddingLeft="125px"
```

from the TextView, to which instead you should add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Can You explain what is that you changed to fix it?

Comment: shrink and stretchColumns aren't flags, they're lists of the columns to make shrinkable/stretchable, so what your xml actually did was say, "make the second ImageView fill all available space"; stretchColumns="3" would have fixed your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_weight attribute on each column.

Comment: 10x. I have tried adding android:layout_weight, but it didnt change the layout.